# How to combine ellipse and regression line together of a scatter plot and also how to show R square on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Want to combine a regression line of the scatter plot with the ellipse and also how to show R square value in a single plot. Also want to remove center blue dot of the plot.Following code and data link, I am using this
[input data link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WhIote1xMEnMO2yd_Awg3ySuThNoD-CQ/view?usp=sharing) want to combine this two plot in single image with R square value in the image too

[image: sample of output image what i am getting using the code][image: regression plot]

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
fir <- read_excel("D:/work/Book1.xlsx", sheet = "tan")
input<- as.data.frame(fir)
data_na =na.omit(input)
head(data_na)
sp <- ggscatter(data_na, x = "v1", y = "v2",
            add = "reg.line",     # Add regressin line
            add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"))
sp 
sd<- dataEllipse(data_na$v1, data_na$v2, levels=c( 0,0.90))# add ellipse
sd 

want to combine/merge (as the data are same for both) this two plots in a single one and need R square value too?
```

Comment: sir i have added the input data and output image but i need to draw in same graph

Comment: please answer someone I am in need of help!

Comment: if you want help you'll need to clarify what you want. The data you posted is not the same as the data used in your plots. The highest value for the x variable in the linked data is about 3.5, yet your plot has values up to almost 6. My answer shows a 90% ellipse around the data you actually shared. I haven't changed it at all. Please check that this is the actual data set you want to use and if necessary edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be easier to draw your plot directly in `ggplot` (note that `ggscatter` is just a wrapper around `ggplot`). You can get the output from `dataEllipse` as a matrix of x, y positions and simply add these to a scatterplot as a `geom_path` to get the desired result:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(car)

ellipse <- dataEllipse(data_na$v1, data_na$v2, 
                       levels = 0.90,
                       draw = FALSE)

ggplot(setNames(data_na, c("x", "y")), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "blue") +
  geom_path(data = as.data.frame(ellipse), color = "blue") +
  theme_pubr()
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
data_na  <- structure(list(v1 = c(176L, 180L, 190L, 118L, 121L, 263L, 202L, 
318L, 282L, 352L, 238L, 325L, 284L, 337L, 368L, 499L, 691L, 374L, 
508L, 371L, 403L, 296L, 244L, 548L, 330L, 630L, 113L, 297L, 219L, 
531L, 454L, 407L, 426L, 454L, 273L, 201L, 318L, 281L, 270L), 
    v2 = c(0.2593678096, 0.4189655053, 0.7775976761, 0.8278505446, 
    0.2388620625, 1.269976995, 0.3011494091, 0.2621149345, 0.3562413688, 
    1.408643646, 1.125793077, 0.1436436738, 0.1076321802, 0.2567930962, 
    0.4841953877, 0.3309999928, 1.340839047, 1.036103417, 0.1997356259, 
    0.3990804449, 0.3864942424, 0.6249310181, 1.36426432, 1.038793083, 
    0.9374712352, 1.242781572, 3.52103437, 3.434022908, 1.356563177, 
    0.4454942428, 0.1573907999, 1.021793082, 0.5268965439, 0.4415632055, 
    1.229494218, 1.432643646, 0.2451838993, 0.4092183845, 1.532045935
    )), row.names = c(NA, 39L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't need a full ellipse, as per my need I have shown in the above image, also you modified the input and data structure , I am not able to get this and  plot like this

Comment: @shanti I have used the data from the link you provided. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience I got the same plot using the given data. Sir, is it possible to start the y-axis from 0 and the x-axis from 100 so that I can ignore the negative axis level?

Comment: @shanti yes. Change the last line from `theme_pubr()` to `theme_pubr() + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(100, 750), ylim = c(0, 4))`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, can you please tell me if I want to replace linear regression line with exponential one, then what modification needed in the code?